# Can not connect to service inside ECS, health checks won't even pass

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rust, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I want to run a Rust application in ECS. The Rust application has a health API and a websocket API. I can not connect to both from my machine to ECS and ECS itself even fails to query the health API using localhost, so I am doing a lot of stuff wrong and I do not know what. It works on my machine.

I checked my security groups, it allows everything. The whole Rust application can be found here: https://github.com/Jasperav/ssh-dockerfile/blob/master/src/main.rs. The relevant code (main.rs) can be found below.

I uploaded the Rust image to ECR public as well: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ecr/repositories/public/465984508737/hello?region=eu-central-1. This can be deployed on an ARM machine.

The steps I took:

1. Made a Rust application which serves 2 endpoints, websocket and HTTP
2. Created an image and uploaded to ECR
3. In ECS, I created a new cluster with 1 public subnet. I used Fargate as infrastructure.
4. In the task definition, I mapped port 3014 and 3015 to TCP HTTP and selected my image. In the health api, I added `CMD-SHELL curl -f localhost:3015/health`
5. I deployed the task as a service to the cluster.
6. I verified I see the logging of the server that it is deployed successfully. However, I can not connect through the public ipv4 address to either the websocket API or health API.

What did I do wrong? This is the relevant code:

```
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use warp::Filter;
use warp::hyper::StatusCode;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("Starting up...");
    let url = "0.0.0.0:3014";
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(url)
        .await
        .unwrap();

    println!("Listing on default URL");

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        run_health_check().await;
    });

    loop {
        match listener.accept().await {
            Ok((stream, _)) => {
                let addr = stream.peer_addr().expect("connected streams should have a peer address");
                println!("Peer address: {}", addr);

                let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(stream)
                    .await
                    .expect("Error during the websocket handshake occurred");

                println!("New WebSocket connection: {}", addr);

                drop(ws_stream);
            }
            Err(e) => panic!("{:#?}", e),
        }
    }
}

async fn run_health_check() {
    let routes = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("health"))
        .map(move || Ok(warp::reply::with_status("", StatusCode::OK)))
        .with(warp::cors().allow_any_origin());

    let socket_address: SocketAddr = "0.0.0.0:3015".to_string().parse().unwrap();

    warp::serve(routes).run(socket_address).await;
}
```

This is the ECS configuration:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:XXXX:task-definition/websocket:3",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "websocket",
            "image": "XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/hello3",
            "cpu": 0,
            "links": [],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "websocket-3015-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 3015,
                    "hostPort": 3015,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                },
                {
                    "name": "websocket-3014-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 3014,
                    "hostPort": 3014,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [],
            "command": [],
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "secrets": [],
            "dnsServers": [],
            "dnsSearchDomains": [],
            "extraHosts": [],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
            "dockerLabels": {},
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/websocket",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "healthCheck": {
                "command": [
                    "CMD-SHELL curl -f localhost:3015/health"
                ],
                "interval": 30,
                "timeout": 5,
                "retries": 3
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "websocket",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 3,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.24"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.container-health-check"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "3072",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "ARM64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2022-12-11T11:19:54.622Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::465984508737:root",
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "ecs:taskDefinition:createdFrom",
            "value": "ecs-console-v2"
        },
        {
            "key": "ecs:taskDefinition:stackId",
            "value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:XX:stack/ECS-Console-V2-TaskDefinition-c246faa1-4ba5-4b54-ac4a-49ae00ab2f0d/8fd98e10-7944-11ed-abb2-0a564ca58c2a"
        }
    ]
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rustlang/rust:nightly-bullseye AS builder

WORKDIR app

COPY . .
RUN cargo build --bin hello -Z sparse-registry

FROM debian:11.5
COPY --from=builder ./app/target/debug/hello .

CMD ["./hello"]
```

Comment: Can you run the docker image locally, and connect to those ports on your local computer? You might try using `ecs exec` to debug this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html You might also consider adding your `Dockerfile` to your question.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, `docker run -d -p 3015:3015 hello` works, I can reach `http://localhost:3015/health`. I also added the Dockerfile in the question. I will try to do the debug the problem using your provided link.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `"command": [],` in the task definition might be overriding `CMD ["./hello"]` from the Dockerfile. I'm not sure what it does with an empty list instead of `null`. Can you try changing that to `"command": ["./hello"],` in the task definition? Also, have you check the container's logs in CloudWatch Logs for any errors or indication that the app isn't starting up properly?